# Using reflection in PHPUnit

Tags: reflection, symfony, phpunit

I'm testing a private method of a class used in Symfony2 project with PHPUnit. 
I'm using the private methods testing strategy (through reflection) described by many developers such as http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2011/08/16/testing-protected-and-private-attributes-and-methods-using-phpunit/

But unfortunately, I got the following error:

> There was 1 error: 1) My\CalendarBundle\Tests\Calendar\CalendarTest::testCalculateDaysPreviousMonth
>   ReflectionException: Class Calendar does not exist /Library/WebServer/Documents/calendar/src/My/CalendarBundle/Tests/Calendar/CalendarTest.php:47

```
<?php
namespace My\CalendarBundle\Tests\Calendar;

use My\CalendarBundle\Calendar\Calendar;

class CalendarTest 
{    
    //this method works fine     
    public function testGetNextYear()
    {
        $this->calendar = new Calendar('12', '2012', $this->get('translator'));        
        $result = $this->calendar->getNextYear();

        $this->assertEquals(2013, $result);
    }

    public function testCalculateDaysPreviousMonth()
    {        
        $reflectionCalendar = new \ReflectionClass('Calendar'); //this is the line

        $method = $reflectionCalendar->getMethod('calculateDaysPreviousMonth');      
        $method->setAccessible(true);

        $this->assertEquals(5, $method->invokeArgs($this->calendar, array()));                 
    }
}
```

Why?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the whole namespaced class name when creating your reflection method, even if you include a `use` statement.

```
new \ReflectionClass('My\CalendarBundle\Calendar\Calendar');
```

This is because you are passing the class name as a string to the constructor, so it doesn't know about your `use` statement and is looking for the class name in the global namespace.

Also, for what it's worth, you don't actually need to create a `ReflectionClass`, then call `getMethod()` on it. Rather, you can directly create a `ReflectionMethod` object.

```
new \ReflectionMethod('My\CalendarBundle\Calendar\Calendar', 'calculateDaysPreviousMonth');
```

That should be essentially the same, but a bit shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm pretty new in unit testing and every suggestion is precious! :)